# How do I get rickshaw to aggregate data into weeks instead of days

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

My x,y values consist of unix epoch times (over about a year) and an integer. I graph the x axis using this:

```
        x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time
          graph: graph
```

The result looks good, but the tick marks are day based (I assume) and I get dips on the weekends when nothing is happening. I would like to aggregate based on weeks. Is it possible for rickshaw to combine the y values together for all times that fall in the same week?

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jTmWC/

Comment: It sounds like this is something that you should do before passing the data to the graph function. You haven't shown us where you get the data from or what format it is in, so we can't really help you with that.

Comment: I can aggregate to weeks manually - but it seems that some kind of mapping to days must be happening, so I was hoping that I could instead map to days. (See the above fiddle url)

Comment: The "mapping" you're seeing is really only the tick labels that d3 sets in a sensible way. It doesn't do any aggregating on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can aggregate the data per month using this code:

```
var aggregated = d3.nest()
               .key(function(d) { return (new Date(+d.x * 1000)).getMonth(); })
               .rollup(function(d) { return d3.sum(d, function(e) { return +e.y; }); })
               .entries(data)
               .map(function(d) { return {x: +d.key, y: d.values}; });
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jTmWC/2/). Note that I also changed the time unit for the axis -- you might need to play around with it a bit to make it show the labels you want.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I was looking for weeks vs month, but I can figure that out. Where are the docs for nest, key and rollup?

Comment: You can find them in the [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use d3 to transform the data, you can always opt to use underscorejs. It's very easy to understand and useful in most javascript projects. I did exactly the same in this screencast on rickshaw: http://tagtree.tv/d3-with-rickshaw-and-angular